# IE7 floated block with ellipsis overflow pushed down the page

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, css-float

I'm seeing an issue in IE7 floating some block content to the left with some long text I would like to ellipsize (or clip) to the right, all inside a container with a constrained width:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>IE7 Float Test</title>
    <style>
      .container {
        width: 200px;
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
      }
      .floater {
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        float: left;
        background: red;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="floater"></div>
      <span class="text">This is some long long long long long long text I want on the same line.</span>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

In IE8+ and every other browser the long text gets ellipsized properly to the right of the floated element. In IE7 the text span gets pushed down below the floated element and is ellipsized down there. Is there any way to keep this on the same line as the floated element in IE7 without resorting to an inline-block hack?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to keep this on the same line as the floated element
>   in IE7 without resorting to an inline-block hack?

Using `display: inline-block` and the hack to make it work in IE7 is an easy way to fix this - I'm not sure why you'd want to avoid it.

http://jsbin.com/orozen

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>IE7 Float Test</title>
    <style>
      .container {
        width: 200px;
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
      }
      .floater {
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        background: red;
        display: inline-block;
        *display: inline;
        zoom: 1;
      }
      .text {
        padding-left: 4px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="floater"></div><span class="text">This is some long long long long long long text I want on the same line.</span>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```